# @interface error in AppDelegate.m class

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, appdelegate

should be a simple solution that I am missing. I have a Tab View Controller driven app that I would like to passcode protect whenever the app is launched or opened by the user. I have created a passcode class & view controller in IB.

I am trying to use the AppDelegate.m class applicationDidLoadInForeground method with the following code:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSUserDefaults *submissionDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([submissionDefaults boolForKey:@"passcodeActive"] == true)
    {   
        PINAuthViewController *pinController = [[PINAuthViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:pinController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

I have imported my PINAuthViewController class in the header

```
#import "PINAuthViewController.h"
```

but I am receiving an error when compiling "No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'presentViewController:animated:completion'.

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong? The intention is to dismiss the passcode View Controller if the passcode is entered correctly.

Many thanks, James

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The app delegate can't present a view controller since it's not a subclass of UIViewController itself.

You need to change your code to:

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:pinController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: You are missing some critical text in that method call.

Comment: Oops, fixed! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks both! My code now compiles but when I run it the view turns black when the line is executed. The below warning is thrown in xcode:

Warning: Attempt to present <PINAuthViewController: 0x1206b610> on <TBMasterViewController: 0x967a890> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Any more advice on how to get around this? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that you move the logic for checking whether the passcode is active or not to your main view controller (the one that gets presented after the app launches), instead of the app delegate. This should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Hesham, I would prefer to have it in the main view controller. Can you please advise where I should put it so that it is triggered only when first opening & when the app is relaunched after being in the background? Bear in mind that I am using a TabBar Controller so have multiple view controllers that could be relaunched into... Thanks, James

Comment: @JamesLCQ: In a method that you call either from your app delegate's `applicationWillEnterForeground:`, or in response to `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`.

Comment: The warning you are getting about the view not being in the window hierarchy is because you are executing the code from `applicationDidLoadInForeground`, so  it attempts to present the view controller before the app has launched and added the main view controller to the app window. If you move your code to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` it should also work fine.

Answer (score 2):

you can also try this code...

```
self.viewController = [[FirstViewController  alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```